# 3com SuperStack II 3000 dead?

Tags: switch

I have a superstack II 3000 10/100, and when it's powered on, the power light, and module status and packet lights all come on, but the switch won't do anything. Nothing out the console port, plugging in a cable to another switch or computer does not make any of the port lights come on.

However, after the switch has been on for about 30 seconds, the "link" light for port 8 slowly comes on, IE, goes from off, to dim, to brighter, to on. Slowly.

The switch does nothing else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We had a couple of these go dead and do some odd things.  No access through console, lights that were on would suddenly do off or change colour. We were able to get warranty replacement on one.  Worth checking with 3COM.  Their "lifetime" warranty is a bit odd so you will need to work with them.  Replacement was pretty quick one we jumped through some hoops.

Comment: Well, the internal power supply in this thing went out... hell, probably three or four years ago, so I opened it up and did some testing and discovered the switch ran on +5 and +12 volts DC, so I've been powering it with a regular computer power supply for the last three years or so, I think the warranty is probably void. :P Mainly I was just curious to know if that light combination had any real relevance or if the switch had finally just conked out.